# QDatastream write data from unsigned char* buffer

Tags: qt

How can I write data from unsigned char* buffer to QDatastream. Threre are methods writeBytes and writeRawData. But they accept const char*. Can I use unsigned char* for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just cast to `const char*`

```
unsigned char array[] =  {1,2,3,4,5};
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream datastream(&ba,QIODevice::ReadWrite);
datastream.writeRawData((const char*) array,5);
```

Comment: Wont it affect on data in buffer?

Comment: no, a pointer is just a memory address. the command above will copy the 5 bytes verbatim from that memory address. You need to be careful when you read those bytes out of the buffer that you cast the pointer back to an unsigned char.